# Why does Ubuntu Installer not have a minimum memory condition?

Tags: installation, memory

When installing Ubuntu, there is a slide for checking met conditions.

I observed that if you have for example only 384 MB of memory, the installer could crash.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/658615 for details.

Comment: Your link is not accessible. I am getting the error 'Sorry, you don't have permission to access this page.' after logging in.

Comment: @LFC_fan: certain types of crashes are marked as security bugs by default, because they might be abusable for buffer overflow exploits or such; I assume that is what happens here.  It will probably become public during the day.

Comment: This bug was marked as private by Apport because the debugging information it has attached can contain sensitive / personal information.

Comment: Is this really a question we can answer here? It seems more like a bug that should be filed against the installer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure your particular crash was due to an out of memory situation (though there's one other bug with a similar traceback to yours that's also a suspected OOM), but there's [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/55775) requesting better dealing with such situations, which Colin Watson (Ubiquity developer) has [acknowledged](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/55775/comments/5).

See "[Meeting Minimum Hardware Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/installation-guide/i386/minimum-hardware-reqts.html)" on the Ubuntu documentation for more information on required specs.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no *absolute* minimum memory requirement that will work for all circumstances, so it's a bit difficult to check for.  I have installed Ubuntu on systems with 256 MiB of RAM, for example.

For example, it depends on what you do in the live environment before you start the installation (or while doing the installation).